# Is not catching an exception undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, exception, language-lawyer, destructor, undefined-behavior

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Widget {
public:
    ~Widget() {
        std::cout << "Destructor Called!";
    }
};

void doStuff() {
    Widget w;
    throw 1;
}

int main() {
    doStuff();
}
```

Because the exception is not caught in main, the compiler *can* arrange for the program to call terminate immediately after the `throw` with `~Widget` not called.

Since the standard does not specify whether or not the destructors are called, is this undefined behavior?

**Note:** The example is from [this](https://youtu.be/fOV7I-nmVXw?t=445) CppCon 2015 talk by Fedor Pikus.

**Edit:** [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23184712/whats-the-compilers-freedom-for-destructor-elision) asks about the compiler's freedom for destructor elision, however it is in a special, different situation. The answer to that question does not apply to this question.

Comment: *Because the exception is not caught in main, the compiler can arrange for the program to call terminate* - this is the well defined behaviour, w/o the un prefix.

Comment: The bad happens if a destructor raises an exception, then abort happens immediately.

Comment: @273K *this is not true. All destructors are being called while stack unwinding until the thread root function is out.* I'm not sure what you mean. I ran the code above with MSVC and ```Destructor Called!``` was not output.

Comment: Implementation defined/unspecified behaviour does not mean the undefined behaviour in any case

Comment: I am glad you aware of it, but I have not asked you, so please don't discuss it with me. `std::terminate` by default simply calls C function `abort`.

Comment: @Anoop Rana you closed this as a dupe to a question where none of the answers provide any detail on the actual standard rules. As this question particularly asks about the formal details of what the language says (language-lawyer tag), I've reopened the question. If there's an appropriate language-lawyer (LL) dupe target we should definitely connect to it, but I propose we do not close LL questions to targets where neither the question nor the answers contain any LL details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is not catching an exception undefined behavior?

No, it is well-defined that this will result in a call to `std::terminate` (with no UB), albeit whether the stack is unwound before the call is implementation-defined, as per [[except.terminate]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/except.terminate):

> /1 In some situations exception handling is abandoned for less subtle
> error handling techniques.
>
> - [...]
> - when the exception handling mechanism cannot find a handler for a thrown exception ([except.handle]), or
>
> /2 In such cases, the function `std​::​terminate` is called. In the
> situation where no matching handler is found, **it is
> implementation-defined whether or not the stack is unwound before
> `std​::​terminate` is called.** [...] An implementation is not permitted to finish stack unwinding prematurely based on a determination that the unwind process will eventually cause a call to the function `std​::​terminate`

Comment: I was not aware that calling functions with side effects could be implementation defined. TIL.

Comment: @MarkWallace Optional copy elision, for example in _named return value optimization_, and elision of `operator new`/`operator delete` calls are other examples where the standard allows the compiler to choose whether or not functions are called, independent of their potential side effects. It is not that uncommon in C++.

Comment: @user17732522: Saying that a function call be omitted is far less horrible than characterizing all situations where useful optimizations might observably affect program behavior as UB.